# Image download - image cannot open

Tags: php

I tried to create some code so that a user can download an image in opencart without right clicking and using `Save as...` but after I created this code and download the image, trying to open the image says the image was damage.

```
<form action="download.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="file" value="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="download" />
</form>
```

---

download.php

```
<?php
$file= $_POST["file"];

header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
header('Content-type: image/gif');
header('Content-type: image/png');

readfile('$file');

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current problem is that when in single quotes, `$file` will not be parsed but taken literally. Use double or no quotes:

```
readfile($file);
```

Other observations:

- Why are you sending five different content-types? That doesn't make sense. You should detect the file's type and send the appropriate image header (or just `application/octet-stream` if you just want to offer a downloadable resource, and not try and display it in the browser).
- You should check that `$file` actually points  to one of the files you want to allow to download. Without that check, an attacker could get *any* file from your site this way, including configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can define the content type multiple times. Determine what the content type is by file extension and include the correct one.

Besides that, use this:

```
readfile($file);
```

No quotes needed. edit: with quotes it doesn't even work, but it will try to open a filename named $file

Comment: ok, when i change to this readfile($file); the page just blank..still same image still damage... :(

Comment: does the file exist on the location you try to open it?

Answer (score 0):

You send multiple Content-Type headers? This is wrong.

You have to determine the Content-Type via the extension (.jpg, .pdf, ...) of the file, and then send the appropriate headers.

Here is a snippet of a download script I've done lately.

```
    $fileName   = $_POST['file']; // or whatever
    $file       = 'someDirectory/' . $fileName; // full path of the file, could also be absolute
    $fileLen    = filesize($file);          
    $ext        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, '.'), 1));

    switch($ext) {
        case 'txt':
            $cType = 'text/plain'; 
        break;              
        case 'pdf':
            $cType = 'application/pdf'; 
        break;
        case 'exe':
            $cType = 'application/octet-stream';
        break;
        case 'zip':
            $cType = 'application/zip';
        break;
        case 'doc':
            $cType = 'application/msword';
        break;
        case 'xls':
            $cType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        break;
        case 'ppt':
            $cType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
        break;
        case 'gif':
            $cType = 'image/gif';
        break;
        case 'png':
            $cType = 'image/png';
        break;
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
            $cType = 'image/jpg';
        break;
        case 'mp3':
            $cType = 'audio/mpeg';
        break;
        case 'wav':
            $cType = 'audio/x-wav';
        break;
        case 'mpeg':
        case 'mpg':
        case 'mpe':
            $cType = 'video/mpeg';
        break;
        case 'mov':
            $cType = 'video/quicktime';
        break;
        case 'avi':
            $cType = 'video/x-msvideo';
        break;

        //forbidden filetypes
        case 'inc':
        case 'conf':
        case 'sql':                 
        case 'cgi':
        case 'htaccess':
        case 'php':
        case 'php3':
        case 'php4':                        
        case 'php5':
        exit;

        default:
            $cType = 'application/force-download';
        break;
    }

    $headers = array(
        'Pragma'                    => 'public', 
        'Expires'                   => 0, 
        'Cache-Control'             => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
        'Cache-Control'             => 'public',
        'Content-Description'       => 'File Transfer',
        'Content-Type'              => $cType,
        'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment; filename="'. $fileName .'"',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary', 
        'Content-Length'            => $fileLen         
    );

    foreach($headers as $header => $data)
        header($header . ': ' . $data); 

    @readfile($file);
```

Comment: sorry..i;m newbie...so how to fix my code..so user can download the image only jpeg.

Comment: message error : Corrupted Content Error ;The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $mimeInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
        $mime_type = finfo_file($mimeInfo, $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);
```

that will help you detect what mimetype to  use with

```
        header('Content-Type: '.$this->_mime_type);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```